# Postgresql Trigger function for setting value in column based on most recent timestamp

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I'm having troubles with creating a trigger function in postgresql which should do the following:

I have a table with category(varchar), edit_date(timestamp) and actual(boolean).

I already have a trigger which sets the actual timestamp on UPDATE or INSERT. The column 'actual' should then say TRUE, if this edit_date is the most current one for a category. So when there are two entities from category a, the one with the more recent edit_date should be set to TRUE, while the other one of this category should be set to FALSE.

Thank you so much for your help, I'm pretty stuck on this one.
Best